# React Functional component is not rendering on props change

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-functional-component

I am using react native for development and i am using functional component for development. but i am facing problem in it. As i am getting callback from function and saving it in a state and i want to that component will render again. but component is not rendering again. Please check and provide me detail in

```
 callBackfn = (callback) => {
        this.setState({ infomationtosend: callback });                    
    }
```

this is working fine as if i will print it on console get state correct output. but as it again goes in the ComponentTreat it doesn't render component again. i also tried useEffect but not working. can anyone provide me solution.

```
<Swiper
   from={0}
   >
    <ComponentTreat
           detailsend={this.state.infomationtosend}
           appName={"sentText"}
           CallBack={(callback) => this.callBackfn(callback)}
      />
 </Swiper>
```

problem in swiper duw to swiper component is not refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Functional Component state change works like this:

```
// Inside parent component
const [info, setInfo] = useState(initalValue);
```

Then to use it in a callback we use closures to access it instead of using `this` keyword.

```
function callback(newValue) {
  setInfo(newValue);
}
```

And pass it accordingly to the child props.

Also, checkout [useCallback()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) if you use a lot of callbacks.